# Why I am unable to run my old Kotlin program in new version of IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am a beginner in Kotlin programming. I started coding simple projects in Kotlin in IntelliJ. The version I was using was 2020.1 But after updating the IDE and also changing my Kotlin version to 1.4, my previous projects are showing some anomalies,

- First major problem I am facing I'm not getting the run button beside my main function neither anywhere else,
  [image: Image1]
- Another problem I am facing is I'm unable to create a Kotlin class or file the way I used to make in previous version by right clicking and selecting option, instead I'm getting some other option in the menu,
  [image: Image2]

So, for understanding it more I made a new project and wrote some simple programs where these anomalies aren't present, though interface of IDE is different than before.
Please, let me know where I am mistaking and how should I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Kotlin 1.4 and jdk 14, this code is working in IntelliJ

```
class DogClass(private val id: Int, private val color: String) {
    fun bark() = println("$color dog $id barks")
}

class Cat(private val id: Int, private val color: String) {
    fun meov() = println("$color cat $id says meow")
}

fun main() {

  val dog1 = DogClass(4, "Black")
  dog1.bark()

  val cat1 = Cat(4, "White")
  cat1.meov()
}
```

[image]

Comment: I was using JDK 1.8.0, but with JDK 14 I tried all codes again and they are working fine.